# I get a 502 eror on a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I tried to install nginx on a php docker container

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Instala Nginx y herramientas necesarias
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx wget

# Instala Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Configura Nginx
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Inicia PHP-FPM y Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 80:80
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

And when I try to acces I get a 502 error, this is the nginx error log

```
2024/02/27 17:50:18 [error] 11#11: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

ther is something wrong on the config?

On the console I can execute php files but not making request using the browser

Comment: Where or when you start php-fpm on port 9000 ? try running docker exec -it ... and verify it inside the container.

Comment: I tried `systemctl start php8.2-fpm`  but there is no sytemctl inside the container, any alternative?

Comment: just to try, run `php-fpm &`

Comment: `[27-Feb-2024 18:42:57] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 51 [27-Feb-2024 18:42:57] NOTICE: ready to handle connections` It seems like is working

Comment: php-fpm was started when you ran the command. Do you get any new msg?

Comment: Have you try:" - ./src:/var/www/html:rw"

Comment: now I get this message 'File not found' but `index.php` is located at  `/var/www/html` seems to be correct

Comment: try removing `location / {` and   `}`  , but keep `root /var/www/html;        index index.php;`  from default.conf . Rebuild or reload and verify php-fpm is still running

Comment: delete `location / { and }`  worked,thank you